# Number of days timer job history is kept?

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs

We've just noticed that our "User Profile Service Application - User Profile Incremental Synchronization" timer job has been failing in our SharePoint 2010 environment for quite some time. This job runs everyday at 1:00 am. When I go to Central Administration > Job History, I can see job history items back to 02/15/15, but nothing further back than that. I'd like to be able to see the last time this timer job ran successfully, which I'm assuming was before 02/15/15.

Does anyone know for how many days timer job history is kept? And, is there anyway to retrieve timer job histories older than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default Number of days timer job history is kept is 7 days.

Timer Job responsible for deleting old timer job logs is `"Delete Job History"`. By default the Delete Job History is supposed to run every Sunday at 5:00 AM . I believe there is no way to get  Timer Job history older than 7 days(Given "Delete Job History" runs successfully periodically) unless a backup of Config Database is taken.

You can check when the job was last executed by checking job definitions from `_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx`